# What is the complete list of values of ST_GeometryType() in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

What is the complete list of return values for PostGIS [ST_GeometryType](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html)()?

The documentation linked above only says:

> Returns the type of the geometry as a string. EG: 'ST_Linestring',
>   'ST_Polygon','ST_MultiPolygon' **etc**.

I'm trying to determine the type of a geometry in a function, but couldn't find the list of all cases. (This is with PostGIS 2.5/2.4)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The full list of PostGIS' [lwgeom type names](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/cdfcda1b712fbda754b369a7a10d7f1c42d6d236/liblwgeom/lwutil.c#L60-L77) is:

- Point
- LineString
- Polygon
- MultiPoint
- MultiLineString
- MultiPolygon
- GeometryCollection
- CircularString
- CompoundCurve
- CurvePolygon
- MultiCurve
- MultiSurface
- PolyhedralSurface
- Triangle
- Tin

Also note there are two other subtle variations from this list using the two functions

- [GeometryType](https://postgis.net/docs/GeometryType.html), which is uppercase, and
- [ST_GeometryType](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html), which has a 3-character `ST_` prefix for OGC / SQL-MM compliance (I think).

Some handy tables to contrast these geometry names:

```
SELECT postgis_typmod_type(i),
    GeometryType((postgis_typmod_type(i) || ' EMPTY')::geometry),
    ST_GeometryType((postgis_typmod_type(i) || ' EMPTY')::geometry)
FROM generate_series(4, 63, 4) AS i;

 postgis_typmod_type |    geometrytype    |    st_geometrytype
---------------------+--------------------+-----------------------
 Point               | POINT              | ST_Point
 LineString          | LINESTRING         | ST_LineString
 Polygon             | POLYGON            | ST_Polygon
 MultiPoint          | MULTIPOINT         | ST_MultiPoint
 MultiLineString     | MULTILINESTRING    | ST_MultiLineString
 MultiPolygon        | MULTIPOLYGON       | ST_MultiPolygon
 GeometryCollection  | GEOMETRYCOLLECTION | ST_GeometryCollection
 CircularString      | CIRCULARSTRING     | ST_CircularString
 CompoundCurve       | COMPOUNDCURVE      | ST_CompoundCurve
 CurvePolygon        | CURVEPOLYGON       | ST_CurvePolygon
 MultiCurve          | MULTICURVE         | ST_MultiCurve
 MultiSurface        | MULTISURFACE       | ST_MultiSurface
 PolyhedralSurface   | POLYHEDRALSURFACE  | ST_PolyhedralSurface
 Triangle            | TRIANGLE           | ST_Triangle
 Tin                 | TIN                | ST_Tin
(15 rows)
```

And a full list of whatever `postgis_typmod_type()` spits out:

```
SELECT i, postgis_typmod_type(i), postgis_typmod_dims(i)
FROM generate_series(4, 63) AS i;

 i  | postgis_typmod_type  | postgis_typmod_dims
----+----------------------+---------------------
  4 | Point                |                   2
  5 | PointM               |                   3
  6 | PointZ               |                   3
  7 | PointZM              |                   4
  8 | LineString           |                   2
  9 | LineStringM          |                   3
 10 | LineStringZ          |                   3
 11 | LineStringZM         |                   4
 12 | Polygon              |                   2
 13 | PolygonM             |                   3
 14 | PolygonZ             |                   3
 15 | PolygonZM            |                   4
 16 | MultiPoint           |                   2
 17 | MultiPointM          |                   3
 18 | MultiPointZ          |                   3
 19 | MultiPointZM         |                   4
 20 | MultiLineString      |                   2
 21 | MultiLineStringM     |                   3
 22 | MultiLineStringZ     |                   3
 23 | MultiLineStringZM    |                   4
 24 | MultiPolygon         |                   2
 25 | MultiPolygonM        |                   3
 26 | MultiPolygonZ        |                   3
 27 | MultiPolygonZM       |                   4
 28 | GeometryCollection   |                   2
 29 | GeometryCollectionM  |                   3
 30 | GeometryCollectionZ  |                   3
 31 | GeometryCollectionZM |                   4
 32 | CircularString       |                   2
 33 | CircularStringM      |                   3
 34 | CircularStringZ      |                   3
 35 | CircularStringZM     |                   4
 36 | CompoundCurve        |                   2
 37 | CompoundCurveM       |                   3
 38 | CompoundCurveZ       |                   3
 39 | CompoundCurveZM      |                   4
 40 | CurvePolygon         |                   2
 41 | CurvePolygonM        |                   3
 42 | CurvePolygonZ        |                   3
 43 | CurvePolygonZM       |                   4
 44 | MultiCurve           |                   2
 45 | MultiCurveM          |                   3
 46 | MultiCurveZ          |                   3
 47 | MultiCurveZM         |                   4
 48 | MultiSurface         |                   2
 49 | MultiSurfaceM        |                   3
 50 | MultiSurfaceZ        |                   3
 51 | MultiSurfaceZM       |                   4
 52 | PolyhedralSurface    |                   2
 53 | PolyhedralSurfaceM   |                   3
 54 | PolyhedralSurfaceZ   |                   3
 55 | PolyhedralSurfaceZM  |                   4
 56 | Triangle             |                   2
 57 | TriangleM            |                   3
 58 | TriangleZ            |                   3
 59 | TriangleZM           |                   4
 60 | Tin                  |                   2
 61 | TinM                 |                   3
 62 | TinZ                 |                   3
 63 | TinZM                |                   4
(60 rows)
```